# How to remove without touching the pluggable.php the wordpress_logged_in cookie to show the username on login?

Tags: login, cookies, pluggable

cookie --> wordpress_logged_in --
admin%7C1684489617%7CTdPaXlizvGyWpJNhCrB8pUcX4725Lrte2OIOnKD3XSx%7Cfca768d6ff2014aefad62fc253b715926c8a907c05231182ba2f1c580836c2a4